# Proper Login Flow and TabBar VC

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am having a few issues accessing the tab bar from the App Delegate to setup the Home Screen Quick Actions. Here is the line of code that I am using to access the tab bar. It is returning false.

```
guard let tabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController else {return false}
```

My tab bar is not my initial VC when the app launches. I have a loading screen during which we authenticate the user token and then it goes to either the login screen or the tab bar controller (which is also the main part of the app) depending on whether the token gets authenticated.

What is best practice for setting up an app with a login screen? The way we are doing it now works fine but I can change it if there is a better way. We are also using Branch for deep linking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a opinion based question and might exist multiple answer to it each of which might be suitable for some specific scenario.

**Approach 1 :**

This is my personal Favorite does not mean that this is the only proper way of doing it. I prefer replacing the application's rootView Controller either with LoginVC or TabBarVC based on wether the token is valid or not. There are multiple answers in SO explaining how can u replace the application's rootVC with proper animation. Pasting the same code would be redundant here.

Why I use this approach?

Keeps my applications navigation controller stack clean and I don't keep any additional VC's in memory than whats actually required.

**Approach 2 :**

This is what many people use for the simplest reason that its simple to use but I personally doesn't prefer it. Modally present either Login VC or Tab bar (both of them might be embedded with UINavigationController obviously and you modally present their NavController's which obviously loads its embedded view controller).

Pros:

1. Easy to code.
2. You can always be sure that app's rootVC is always fixed and it has presented either LoginVC or TabBarVC. So parsing and accessing the VC's becomes fairly simple.

Cons:

The Landing VC which modally presents unnecessarily remains in Applications Navigation stack through out the apps life cycle. I clearly don't favor this.

**EDIT :**

As OP has clearly mentioned that he is using approach 2 and wants to know how to access specific VC in tab bars selected index am updating the code show the same.

Code is not intended for Copy paste, code might contain syntactic error. Code provided below is only intended for providing the idea.

Assuming your LandVC does not have UINavigationController embedded to it.

```
if let landVC = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {
            if let presentedVC = landVC.presentedViewController {
                if presentedVC is LoginVC {
                    //this is login VC
                }
                else if presentedVC is UITabBarController {
                    let currentlySelectedVC  = (presentedVC as! UITabBarController).viewControllers?[(presentedVC as! UITabBarController).selectedIndex]
                    //now check what type VC it is and use it accordingly
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Since it looks like we are using the second method and it is not bad practice to use this method, how would we access the tab bar controller from the app delegate to set the selectedIndex when implementing home screen quick actions?

Comment: @nevin-jethmalani : Please have a look at the code posted above. The above code will help you fetch tab bar and VC at selected tab index from anywhere in your app. I never said second method is not a bad practice. In my view second approach is still not a great idea because it leaves a VC unnecessarily left in the memory. I don't prefer it :)

Comment: @nevin-jethmalani : Please consider accepting the answer if it helped u